# Utilizar fichero css en un documento php

Tags: php, css

Veran, estoy haciendo unas paginas php que simulan la gestión de las reservas de un hotel. Para darle estilo a la página, estoy utilizando un documento css.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que ponga en body afecta a toda la pagina php. Lo que ponga en form, a los formularios solo.
La cuestión es como poner sentencias que afecte a lo que haya en un `<?php ?>`.
Probé con `php{}`, pero no funciona. También fallo `?php{}`

Edito: He encontrado una chapuza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo llamo chapuza porque tendre que poner esto en cada php, pero parece que no hay modo de pedir de forma directa a un css que actue en un php.

Comment: lo que hay en el php esta dentro del body, pero te recomiendo ponerles algún identificador, si quieres sube el código php y te digo como quedaría

Comment: te refieres a etiquetas que se crean dentro de `<?php ?>` , como `<?php echo "<div class='a' > </div>"; ?>`

Comment: agrega el codigo php/html de esa forma es dificl

Answer (score 0):

Para esto deberías crear con contenedor al momento de imprimir los datos que traes de PHP y darle los estilos a ese contenedor.

```
<?php 
    echo '<div class="contenedor_php"><p>Contenido traído por php</p></div>';
?>
```

Y en tu archivo css:

```
.contenedor_php{
    /*Estilos relacionados*/
}
```

Comment: He encontrado un modo. Lo pondre arriba.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez Es mejor que si hallaste una forma lo pongas como otra respuesta, o en su caso especifiques que eso es lo que has intentado en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Ya descubri como solucionarlo.
No puedo poner un codigo css que apunte a php, pero si pongo una etiqueta que aborde el fragmento php, afectara tambien a lo que haya dentro del codigo.

Es decir, que si tengo en un css:

```
p{
// Código
}
```

Y luego hago en el otro fichero:

```
<p>
<?php
// Instrucciones
?>
</p>
```

Pues lo que tenga para en 'p' tambien afectara al PHP.